# What is the purpose of name mangling in C++?

Tags: c++, naming, overloading

I've read in an article that a compiler changes the names (name mangling) of functions (that have same names) to avoid names conflict.

Consider following example.

```
void fun(int x)
{
    cout<<x<<endl;  
}

void fun(float x)
{
    cout<<x<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    fun(10);
    fun(10.5f);

    return 0;
}
```

Above is a very simple example for function overloading. Here when code is compiled the compiler will change the function name so that linker can link between two different calls.

**Question: What is the need of mangling?**

Since the arguments have different datatype, that could have been enough to link with proper function. Why does then, the compiler perform Name Mangling?

Comment: Because that's how the compiler can know what function has what parameters?

Answer (score 6):

The linker doesn't know about overloading (it has to be generic for multiple languages). All it knows about are *symbols* that it needs to resolve.

The compilers name-mangling creates two different symbols for the two function overloads, allowing the linker to resolve them to the correct function.